# ADO.Net EDM: There is no matching for the set EntitySet or AssociationSet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have created a database. There are three tables: users, articles and comments. Articles can be created by users and commented by them, so we have three one-to-many relationships between these tables: users <-> articles,users <-> comments, articles <-> comments. While processing the program there is a "System.Data.MappingException" exception:

> Models.DB.msl(3,4) : error 3027: There is no matching for the set EntitySet or AssociationSet - UserComment.

Question is: can it be caused by circuit kind of relationship between tables, or because of erroneous setting of relationships' properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to relationship mapping error. Check your entity relationship mapping in edm.
May this will lead you to solution.